# Make element not focusable - IE bug?

Tags: javascript, css, focus

I have a popup menu with several icons that the user has to click to receive additional options in that menu. The menu is a div with tabindex set so that it can receive focus, and its `focusout` handler is set to close the menu. The icons have no tabindex so clicking on them should not close the menu, which works correctly in Chrome/FF. In IE, however, clicking on an icon seems to close the menu. What's going on in here?

I made a fiddle to test this further and observed some very strange behavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/mdd7kqxm/3/

If you open the menu and click on the text, the menu will close (in IE). If you, however, remove the `width` attribute from the menu item, it will no longer receive focus and cause the menu to close. How does `width` attribute affect the elements ability to receive focus? Replacing `div` element with an arbitrary name (like `foo`) also prevents this behavior.

Here's the fiddle code:

```
// css
.menubox {
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
.menuitem {
    width: 40px;
}

// html
<div id="showbtn">Show menu</div>
<div class="menubox" tabindex="1">
    <div class="menuitem">Hello</div>
</div>

// js
$("#showbtn").click(function() {
    $(".menubox").show().focus();
});
$(".menubox").focusout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Please include your JSFiddle code in your post.

Comment: That is a very bizarre way to do menus...